# Java unmarshall xml element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am just beginner in java. I have a xml response as follows.I want to extract elements from the response

```
<result>
<status>success</status>
<function>get_list</function>
<controlid>testControlId</controlid>
<listtype start="0" end="9" total="3463">arpayment</listtype>
<data>
</data>
</result>
```

I need to get the start,count,total in the  element.
I have two class files for this
List type.class

```
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

    public class Listtype
    {
    @XmlAttribute
    public
    Integer start;
    @XmlAttribute
    public
    Integer end;
    @XmlAttribute
    public
    Integer total;
    @XmlValue
    String value;

Result.class

    public class Result
    {   
    @XmlElement
    String status;
    @XmlElement
    String function;
    @XmlElement
    String controlid;
    @XmlElement
    public
    Listtype listtype;
```

This is how I process my xml

```
String body = <XMLREQUEST>
StringBuffer response = null;
HttpURLConnection connection;
Object endPoint = "https://XXXX.phtml";
URL obj = new URL((String) endPoint);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
//add request header
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "XML");
String urlParameters = body;
System.out.println(urlParameters);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
+ connection.getResponseCode());
}
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
response = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
Result r = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(response.toString()), Result.class);
System.out.println("\tListtype start: " + r.listtype.start);
System.out.println("\tListtype end  : " + r.listtype.end);
System.out.println("\tListtype total: " + r.listtype.total);
```

How do I get the element value of start,end,total in the main function

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a Java class modelling the `<result>` XML tag, and also a class modelling the `<listtype>` XML tag. Normally you annotate the Java class attributes with [`@XmlElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html) to indicate that they are from a value of an XML tag, you can use [`@XmlAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html) to indicate that the Java attribute is in an attribute of an XML tag:

```
class Listtype {
    @XmlAttribute
    Integer start;
    @XmlAttribute
    Integer end;
    @XmlAttribute
    Integer total;
    @XmlValue
    String value;
}

class Result {
    @XmlElement
    String status;
    @XmlElement
    String function;
    @XmlElement
    String controlid;
    @XmlElement
    Listtype listtype;
}
```

And you can unmarshal the result XML using the [`JAXB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html) class like this (here I assumed the XML data is in file `"result.txt"`):

```
// Unmarshal: 1 line only
Result r = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("result.xml"), Result.class);

// The rest is just printing it to the console:
System.out.println("Status   : " + r.status);
System.out.println("Function : " + r.function);
System.out.println("Controlid: " + r.controlid);
System.out.println("Listtype : " + r.listtype.value);
System.out.println("\tListtype start: " + r.listtype.start);
System.out.println("\tListtype end  : " + r.listtype.end);
System.out.println("\tListtype total: " + r.listtype.total);
```

Output:

```
Status   : success
Function : get_list
Controlid: testControlId
Listtype : arpayment
    Listtype start: 0
    Listtype end  : 9
    Listtype total: 3463
```

**Edit:**

If your XML is present in a `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder` or as a `String`, you can unmarshal it by creating a [`StringReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) as the source instead of a `File`:

```
String s = "<result>...</result>"; // XML content as a String
// Unmarshal: 1 line only
Result r = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(s), Result.class);
```

If you have it in a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` named `sb`, you can convert it to `String` using its `toString()` method:

```
Result r = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(sb.toString()), Result.class);
```

Comment: I assigned the XML response to the string buffer. I will have to unmarshall from the stringbuffer

Comment: @Karthi See my edited answer to unmarshal from `String` or `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Hi @icza. I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException error now in the lines : System.out.println("\tListtype start: " + r.listtype.start);
System.out.println("\tListtype end  : " + r.listtype.end);
System.out.println("\tListtype total: " + r.listtype.total);

Comment: @Karthi That means your `Listtype` object was not created. Most likely you used different java code or XML. If you want further help on that, post the exact Java code and XML you use, either by editing the question or as a new question.

Comment: Hi @icza I have modified the accordingly and added my main class also.

Comment: @Karthi Right before you call `JAXB.unmarshal()`, please print the XML `response.toString()` to the console and post it please. Most likely it is not in the format you expect it.